# Azure container instance is failing again and again

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I am Trying to load simple windows docker image in Azure container instance, The only thing I see different in this image is size, which is around 10 GB but it should not be an issue. **microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.6.2-runtime** is the image, I am trying to use with windows container.

Screenshot is attached below:-
[image]

All suggestions are welcome to do the same using any Azure container instance over windows containers (Windows server core 2016).

Configuration using for instance: 6GB RAM and 2 Cores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will want to use this docker image: microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016 as ACI only supports containers on Windows Server 2016 images.

This guide is worth reviewing:
https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/master/samples/aspnetapp/deploy-container-to-aci.md

Comment: Thanks @KWilson for the solution